# lazyload dynamic drive content tabs

Tags: javascript, jquery, tabs, lazy-loading

i create any tabs content using [dynamic drive tabs content](http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex17/tabcontent.htm) . if i have `4 tabs` and `4 div` content, all div content tabs loaded in a moment. this not Interesting. in act, better way : `load first tabs 1 (div content1) then tabs 2 (div content2) then tabs 3 (div content3) then tabs 4 (div content4)`. i think [jquery lazyload plugin](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload) Can help. any methods, way/solutions for this problem!? thanks.

Html:

```
<ul id="flowertabs" class="shadetabs">
<li><a href="#" rel="tcontent1" class="selected">Tab 1</a></li>
<li><a href="#" rel="tcontent2">Tab 2</a></li>
<li><a href="#" rel="tcontent3">Tab 3</a></li>
<li><a href="#" rel="tcontent4">Tab 4</a></li>
</ul>

<div style="border:1px solid gray; width:450px; margin-bottom: 1em; padding: 10px">

<div id="tcontent1" class="tabcontent">
Tab content 1 here<br />Tab content 1 here<br />
</div>

<div id="tcontent2" class="tabcontent">
Tab content 2 here<br />Tab content 2 here<br />
</div>

<div id="tcontent3" class="tabcontent">
Tab content 3 here<br />Tab content 3 here<br />
</div>

<div id="tcontent4" class="tabcontent">
Tab content 4 here<br />Tab content 4 here<br />
</div>

</div>
```

JS source : [HERE](http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex17/tabcontent/tabcontent.js)

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var myflowers=new ddtabcontent("flowertabs") //enter ID of Tab Container
myflowers.setpersist(true) //toogle persistence of the tabs' state
myflowers.setselectedClassTarget("link") //"link" or "linkparent"
myflowers.init()

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you thought about using [JQuery UI Tabs](http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/) plugin?

It gives flexible and powerfull solution for almost any task with tabs.

Answer (score 0):

So you want to load the tab contents when a user clicks the tab, right? If that's what you want to do you can attach a listener to the link elements and when one is clicked dynamically load content into the tab content area.

```
// Example using jQuery
var urls = {
    'tcontent1': 'url-to-content-1'
  , 'tcontent2': 'url-to-content-2'
  , 'tcontent3': 'url-to-content-3'
  , 'tcontent4': 'url-to-content-4'
}
$('#flowertabs a').on('click', function() {
    var tabContentId = this.attr('del')
    if (this.attr('loaded') !== undefined) {
        $.ajax(urls[tabContentId]).done(function(html) {
            $('#' + tabContentId).html(html).attr('loaded','loaded')
        })
    }
})
```